# Engulfing lemma : PL homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, triangulation, simplicial-complex

I am looking for a proof of the following result for $n \geq 1$, $n \neq 4$.

Let $(K,h)$ be a PL structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. a locally finite simplicial complex $K$ and a homeomorphism  $h : |K| \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the star of any simplex of $K$ is homeomorphic to a sphere).

Let $0 < \epsilon < a < b$ be three numbers and let $O_n:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| < 1\}$.

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism, there exists a homeomorphism $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which is PL relative to $(K,h)$ (i.e. there exists a subdivision $K_1$ of $K$ such that for each closed simplex $\sigma \in K_1$, $h^{-1} \circ g \circ h$ restricted to $\sigma$ is the restriction of an affine map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ on $\sigma$) and is such that:

- $g|_{f[(a-\epsilon)O_n]} = Id$
- $g|_{f[(b+\epsilon)O^c_n]} = Id$
- $g[f(aO_n)] \supseteq f(bO_n)$
- the angle between $g^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ is $< \epsilon$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Any idea on a paper that would prove this? I think this is somehow related to the generalized Poincare conjecture in the case of PL manifolds but this is more precise than the statement of this conjecture.

I just need to quote a reference that would handle this result.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The last condition, I think, makes it impossible already for $n=2$. Just imagine $f=id$ on $(a-\epsilon)O_n$, but $f^{-1}$ "twisting" by $\pi$ on a sequence of (small) disjoint disks accumulating to the boundary circle of   $(a-\epsilon)O_n$ (and mapping every such small disk to itself).